# Почему функция filter фильтрует 0 вместе с заданными по условию?

Tags: python, list, список, filter

```
a1 = [-10, 27, 1000, -1, 0, -30]
list(filter(lambda x: x if x >= 0 else False,a1))
```

Данный код фильтрует 0 вместе с отрицательными числами. Почему так?

Answer (score 5):

[filter(func, iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) - фильтрует элементы `iterable`, проверяя условие `bool(func(item)) == True`. Когда элементом является `0` - вы вместо того чтобы вернуть `True` / `False`, возвращаете сам элемент, т.е. `0`.

```
In [157]: bool(0)
Out[157]: False
```

> Note that `filter(function, iterable)` is equivalent to the generator
>   expression `(item for item in iterable if function(item))` if function
>   is not `None` and `(item for item in iterable if item)` if function is
>   `None`.

---

Сделайте так - выглядит понятнее и работать будет правильно:

```
In [156]: list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, a1))
Out[156]: [27, 1000, 0]
```

Comment: да такое решение мне нравится, спасибо!

Comment: @nich123, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Answer (score 4):

Фильтруется потому что ты вместо истинного значения возвращаешь сам элемент, а 0 ложен. Надо возвращать значение самого условия, а не городить условный оператор. Но можно вообще записать красивее сразу через список с выражением.

https://ideone.com/mJJVRp

```
a = [-10, 27, 1000, -1, 0, -30]
b = list(filter(lambda x: x >= 0, a))
c = [x for x in a if x >= 0]

print(b)
print(c)
```